# Page Content Under Nav-bar Moves with CSS Animations

Tags: html, css

I need help with my horizontal nav-bar that is at the top of my webpage.I am using a CSS animation to make my nav-button's font-size increase on focus and hover. I only want my nav-bar to move when nav-items are focused or hovered. My only problem is that the content beneath the nav-bar moves down when my nav-button is focused or hovered. I only need help with making the content beneath my nav-bar unaffected by the growing font-size of my focused or hovered nav-buttons.

```
    /*NAVBAR CSS STARTS HERE*/
    nav {
    margin-left: 15%;
    }
    .navbar {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar li{
    display: inline;
    }
    .nav-link a {
      margin-left: 1%;
      padding: 14px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.548);
      font-size: 20px;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 5px; 
  }
  
  .nav-link a:hover, .nav-link a:focus {
    animation: grow 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  
  /*nav-bar css ends here*/
```

Here's the HTML below for one of the webpages on my website.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Maurice Rogers">
    <title>My Short Bio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="backgroundImg">
    <header id="page-top">
    <h1><span>Maurice Rogers</span></h1>
    <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" 
    href="index.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="technical- 
    resume.html">Technical Resume</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="my- 
    animations.html">Animations</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a class="nav-link" href="me- 
    surfing.html">Surfing</a></li>          
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>   
    <main>

    <br/>
    <h2><span>My Bio</span></h2>
    <br/>
    <div class="box">
    <p>I love to code. I find it to be very fun, interesting, and 
    rewarding. You can <a href="technical-resume.html" 
    accesskey="t">find my Technical Resume here</a>. I also have other 
    cool interests. I've spent many hours making animations. You can 
    <a href="my-animations.html" accesskey="a">view my animations 
    here</a>. I've been surfing all my life. It really is one of my 
    favorite things to do. You can <a href="me-surfing.html" 
    accesskey="s">see me surfing here</a>.</p>
    </div>

    </main>
    <footer>
    <nav>
    <a class="ftr-nav-link" href="index.html">Back to top</a>
    </nav>
    <h4 class="copy-right">&copy; 2021 Maurice Rogers</h4>
    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide some code for us to see, but off the top of my head if you use `transform: scale()` on your hover rule it might solve the issue of the content around your text moving.

Comment: @BertW I added code to my post. Does ```transform: scale()``` not affect the surrounding content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify your code to get the desired result. I used `transform: scale()` to increase the font-size without affecting the buttons. Apparently if you use `display: inline` then `scale()` will not work so I changed around your code and use flexbox properties. Also there were a few issues with your html, you declared the class `nav-link` on both your `a` and `li`, so I removed the class from `a`. Hope this works for you.

```css
 /*NAVBAR CSS STARTS HERE*/
    nav {
    margin-left: 15%;
    }
    .navbar {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .nav-link {
      margin-left: 1%;
      padding: 14px 30px;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.548);
      font-size: 20px;
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border-radius: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 5px; 
      transition: transform .5s;
  }
.nav-link a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .nav-link a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  
  /*nav-bar css ends here*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="Maurice Rogers">
    <title>My Short Bio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="backgroundImg">
    <header id="page-top">
    <h1><span>Maurice Rogers</span></h1>
    <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li class="nav-link"><a  
    href="index.html">Bio</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a  href="technical- 
    resume.html">Technical Resume</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a  href="my- 
    animations.html">Animations</a></li>
        <li class="nav-link"><a  href="me- 
    surfing.html">Surfing</a></li>          
    </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>   
    <main>

    <br/>
    <h2><span>My Bio</span></h2>
    <br/>
    <div class="box">
    <p>I love to code. I find it to be very fun, interesting, and 
    rewarding. You can <a href="technical-resume.html" 
    accesskey="t">find my Technical Resume here</a>. I also have other 
    cool interests. I've spent many hours making animations. You can 
    <a href="my-animations.html" accesskey="a">view my animations 
    here</a>. I've been surfing all my life. It really is one of my 
    favorite things to do. You can <a href="me-surfing.html" 
    accesskey="s">see me surfing here</a>.</p>
    </div>

    </main>
    <footer>
    <nav>
    <a class="ftr-nav-link" href="index.html">Back to top</a>
    </nav>
    <h4 class="copy-right">&copy; 2021 Maurice Rogers</h4>
    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try putting a position: absolute on your ul tag and start from there.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it negatively affected my nav-bar design. I appreciate your effort though.

Comment: Right, position: absolute takes whatever dive and it's children out of the normal html flow. So you can position it at the very top of the screen, middle of the screen, wherever you want. The trick is to make a wrapper around that absolute div that's positioned absolutely, give that div a specific size, then position the other div absolutely within that so that growing and shrinking doesn't affect the rest of the flow. I'm sure there are other ways to do it but this is the easiest by far imho.